# unable to cast object of type 'system.dbnull' to type 'system.byte '. c#

Tags: asp.net

when i am trying to check if there is an image in that row for that particular it shows error when i set if the value == null, code works fine when image is found but i want to print no screenshot when there is no image. All this is done in gridview

```
protected void gvupdationsummary_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

    if(dr!=null)
    {
        //string src = Convert.DBNull(imageUrl);

        string imageUrl="";
        if (imageUrl!=null)
        {
            Convert.IsDBNull(imageUrl);
            imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dr["imgdata"]);
            (e.Row.FindControl("image1") as Image).ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
        else
        {
            Convert.IsDBNull(imageUrl);
            imageUrl = null;
            (e.Row.FindControl("image1") as Image).ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure that the `DBNull` exception occurred in this cast: `Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dr["imgdata"])`. You should use `IsDbNull()` or `DBNull.Value` with `if` condition to check against `DBNull`.

Comment: yes the error is in this line only and kindly provide the code if possible.

Comment: [`Convert.IsDBNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.isdbnull) is a method **returning a bool**. It doesn't do anything to the argument and you are ignoring the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception occurred because `dr["imgdata"]` contains `DBNull.Value`, which cannot directly converted to byte array. You should put a check against `DBNull.Value` before using cast.

Take note that [`Convert.IsDbNull()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.isdbnull?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns `bool` value, use it to check inside `if` condition like example below:

```
if (!Convert.IsDbNull(dr["imgdata"]))
{
    imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dr["imgdata"]);
    // do other things
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

**Note:**

`Convert.IsDBNull(imageUrl)` is unnecessary because empty string should be checked with `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead of `Convert.IsDbNull()`.

Comment: Bro, when  i used the code of yours, the row having image is not showing the image all image fields are blank

Comment: Sounds like `IsNullOrEmpty()` affects the image viewing, even `dr["imgdata"]` is not contain `DBNull.Value`. You should remove that check and just use `Convert.IsDbNull()` only.